# Which of these select statements is "better," and why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table person and role.
I have to all the persons based on role.

```
select person.* from person inner join role on
person.roleid = role.id Where role.id = @Roleid
```

or

```
select person.* from person inner join role on
person.roleid = role.id AND role.id = @Roleid
```

Which one of the above two solutions is better and Why?

Answer (score 13):

The first is better because it's logically coherent.  The scoping condition isn't relevant to the join, so making it a part of the join is a kludge, and in this case an unhelpful one.

Comment: Although in at least one case, I discovered that "explain plan" gave me much better results if I put the scope into the join statement.

Comment: That's depressing, but unsurprising. :)

Comment: For simple queries like this, it shouldn't make a difference, but for complex queries or for some outer joins, it might.  This is because (or so I once heard) the ON clause is resolved before the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference in the relational algebra.  Criteria from the where and inner joins like this are interchangeable.  I use both depending on the readability and situation.

In this particular case, you could also use:

```
select person.* from person WHERE person.roleid = @Roleid
```

The only difference being that it does not require that a row exist in the role table (but I assume you have referential integrity for that) and it will not return multiple rows if roleid is not unique (which it almost certainly is in most scenarios I could foresee).

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet is to try these queries out and run them through MS Sql's execution plan.  I did this and the results look like this:

[Execution plan showing identical performance of queries http://img223.imageshack.us/img223/6491/querycompare.png](http://img223.imageshack.us/img223/6491/querycompare.png)

As you can see, the performance is the same (*granted, running it on your db may produce different results.*)  So, the **best** query is the one that follows the consistent convention you use for writing queries.

Comment: +1 About time someone finally pointed out "Just run them through the profiler and look at the execution plan" :)

Comment: Nice post.  It would be better if indexes were present on these tables to give more typical plans.

Comment: Unfortunately, many tables don't use indexes. Difference between a database developer and application developer, one uses indexes, the other doesn't think about them.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding things correctly - The tables in question are doing a clustered index scan, doesn't that mean they're indexed?

Comment: @Dwight T: No, application developers tend to not know about indexes...  @LFSR: YEs that does mean he has indexed, in fact in SQL Server 2005 this USUALLY means they're primary keys (i haven't seen a clustered index on anything, but i could and probably am wrong).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server should evaluate those queries identically. Personally, I would use the AND. I like to keep all of the criteria for a joined table in the join itself so that it's all together and easy to find.

Comment: Yes, they should evaluate identically, so it's a matter of personal preference, which we can't answer for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Both queries are identical.  During query processing, SQL server applies the WHERE filter immediately after applying the join condition filter, so you'll wind up with the same things filtered either way.

Comment: More correct:  During query optimization, SQL server chooses the order in which query tasks are accomplished.  It might do the filtering task first, or it might do the joining task first.  Both queries require both of these tasks.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer #1, I believe that it expresses the intent of the statement better. That you are joining the two tables based on the roleid & role.id and that you are filtering based on @Roleid

```
SELECT person.* 
FROM person INNER JOIN role ON person.roleid = role.id 
Where role.id = @Roleid
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlserver probably has an equivalent of the "explain plan" statement that Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL all support in one form or another.  It can be very useful in telling you how the query parser and optimizer is going to treat your query.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the first one, but remember when done testing the code you should explicitly select each table, instead of doing select *

Answer (score 0):

As you are not fetching columns from `role` you'd better not include it in the `FROM` clause at all. Use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   person
WHERE  person.roleid IN (SELECT id FROM role WHERE id = @Roleid)
```

This way the optimizer sees only one table in the `FROM` clause and can quickly figure out the cardinality of the resultset (that is the number of rows in the resultset is <= the number of rows in table `person`).

When you throw two tables with a `JOIN` the optimizer has to look in the `ON` clause to figure out if these tables are equi-joined and whether unique indexes exist on the joined columns. If the predicate in the `ON` clause is complicated one (multiple ANDs and ORs) or simply wrong (sometimes very wrong) the optimizer might choose sub-optimal join strategy.

Obviously this particular sample is very contrived, because you can filter `persons` by `roleid = @Roleid` directly (no join or sub-query) but the considerations above are valid if you had to filter on other columns in `role` (@Rolename for instance).

Answer (score -4):

Would there be any performance hit/gain by using this query?

```
SELECT person.* FROM person,role WHERE person.roleid=role.id AND role.id=@RoleID
```

Comment: No, that's just an implicit INNER JOIN.

Comment: no, this is a poor syntax, the join standard has been out since 1992, it's time to stop using that obselecent syntax. It is harder to maintain, it doesn't work correctly in SQl Server at all if you use a left join and it is far more likely to result inan accidental cross join.